# Trying to remove faulty installation of Jenkins

Tags: linux, debian, java, dpkg, jenkins

On an old Debian machine running squeeze I have a faulty installation of jenkins which prevents me from doing most basic apt actions like install, upgrade etc.

I have tried running

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq jenkins

dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
reinstall it before attempting a removal.
(Reading database ... 139335 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jenkins ...
Found an incorrect Java version
Java version found:
java version "1.5.0" gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.4.5 Copyright (C) 2007 Free 
Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying 
conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS 
FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Aborting
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing jenkins (--remove):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
jenkins
```

I have tried upgrading Java version following the guidelines here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-debian-8

But I get a similar error as the one above. How can I proceed to completely remove Jenkins from the machine, I have no need for it?

Update: After trying to update Java version I now get this instead:

```
Found an incorrect Java version
Java version found:
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.13) (6b18-1.8.13-0+squeeze2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode, sharing)
```

EDIT:
Tried Antonio's answer but got the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 33, in <module>
    from ALChacks import *
File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/ALChacks.py", line 32, in <module>
sys.stderr.write(_("Can't set locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are    correct!\n"))
NameError: name '_' is not defined
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "sv_SE.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing jenkins (--remove):
Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
reinstall it before attempting a removal.
configured to not write apport reports
Errors were encountered while processing:
jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you try following these instructions from the error messsage? `Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
reinstall it before attempting a removal.`

Comment: Also: `invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "stop" failed.`  Any idea why it failed? Can you manually start/stop the jenkins service?

Comment: I have tried my best reinstalling it but it fails with same error mesasge.

No idea why start/stop fails, it fails if I do it manually as well.

Comment: Can you post the Jenkins logs and the output of `service jenkins stop`?

Comment: It doesn't write anything to the logs ```/var/log/jenkins``` is empty. The output is the same as in the original post under "Update"

Answer (score 2):

I suffered the same on a Debian 7 Wheezy.

The problem is you have an outdated Java version. Jenkins needs Java 8. Whenever you try to uninstall Jenkins, your system try to execute an uninstall script associated to Jenkins. Then this script fails because you don't have the right Java version and the removal is ended.

I first tried to upgrade Java, but I found exactly the same fail as the system tried to stop jenkins before upgrading Java. Even when Jenkins wasn't running at all, because you rememeber? we don't have the right Java version.

So we are trapped in some kind of circular dependence, and we need to break it.

This worked for me:

1. Edit `/etc/init.d/jenkins` . I like to use vim, but use your prefered editor. Remember you will need `sudo` privileges in order to edit this file.
2. This is the script used to start and stop Jenkins, the one is realizing we don't have the right Java version, etc.
3. Put the whole file under comments. To do so prepend the symbol `#` to every line. With vim I got it done easily with `:%s/^/#/`
4. Go the last line (`G` in vim).
5. Remove the `#` before `exit 0`, that will tell the system the script was succesful.
6. Now you can launch `sudo aptitude remove jenkins`

I hope it's useful. Make me note if it didn't work, please.

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately, see output under "EDIT" in my original post (it was too long to paste here)

Comment: Try to use `apt-get remove` or `aptitude remove` they work at a higher level than `dpkg` and some times they are able to deal with issues `dpkg` is not able to.

Comment: Or do the following. 1) comment Jenkins script as I told you 2) reinstall Jenkins  (as you're being told to in the error description) 3) repeat 1), and  4) try to remove it again.